# Can I insert a variable into a keyboard press with pynput?

Tags: python, keyboard, pynput

I'm trying to create a random code input system for fun. I want to insert a random integer into the keyboard.press() function and execute it but I cannot figure out how to do this. Are there any solutions?

I've already tried creating a list, picking randomly from that list, setting it to a variable, trying to make it into a value, and making it into a function. I cant find this question anywhere online or figure it out.

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
import random

keyboard = Controller()


def RandInt():
    random.randint(0,9)

chars = random.randint(0,9)

keyboard.press()
keyboard.release()
keyboard.press(Key.enter)
keyboard.release(Key.enter)
```

What I want currently is just one random number output and a return key press, but instead i get 
    line 372, in press
        if resolved.is_dead:
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_dead'
or
    line 548, in _resolve
        raise ValueError(key)
    ValueError: chars
or
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
    AttributeError: chars

Answer (score 1):

As far as understand doing something like this should do what you want :

```
import random
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

def press_release_char(char):
    keyboard.press(char)
    keyboard.release(char)

press_release_char(str(random.randint(0,9)))
press_release_char(Key.enter)
```

As from the documentation of pynput https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#controlling-the-keyboard

You can add a loop around the `press_release_char(str(random.randint(0,9)))` line for multiple digits

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!